# 2 bundles in webpack: 1 for js+css and 1 for css only

Tags: css, sass, webpack

I've easily set up my webpack config for js+css and now I got stuck trying to update the config to generate a css-only bundle. The reason for this need is to separate bundles for landing page and the app itself. Here is my config (pretty much simplified but I kept everything that might be related):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'bootstrap-loader',
    './web/static/app/js/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: './priv/static',
    filename: 'js/app.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2', 'stage-0'],
      }
    }, {
      test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//,
      loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery'
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?localIdentName=[hash:base64]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 versions!sass')
    }],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.scss', '.css'],
    modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", __dirname + "/web/static/app/js"],
    alias: {
      styles: __dirname + '/web/static/app/styles'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css')
  ]
};
```

currently it generates css/app.css and js/app.js just fine and what I'm trying to achieve is generating css/landing.css from web/static/landing/index.scss

What I've tried:

I added `'./web/static/landing/js/index.js'` to `module.exports.entry`, added

```
var extractSCSS_app = new ExtractTextPlugin('css/app.css');
var extractSCSS_landing = new ExtractTextPlugin('css/landing.css');
```

and replaced scss loader with following:

```
}, {
      test: /app\/.*?\.scss$/,
      loader: extractSCSS_app.extract('style', 'css?localIdentName=[hash:base64]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 versions!sass')
    }, {
      test: /landind\/.*?\.scss$/,
      loader: extractSCSS_landing.extract('style', 'css?localIdentName=[hash:base64]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 versions!sass')
    }, {
```

and in plugins I've put

```
extractSCSS_app,
extractSCSS_landing,
```

Almost every article about webpack I've found describing js+css bundles configuration and docs are not clear to me regarding this question, so what I've tried is what I imagined could be right. Unfortunately it wasn't and that's why I'm here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just quickly skimming through your question. could it be a typo. bring attention to this line

```
 test: /landind\/.*?\.scss$/
```

landind instead of landing? late night coding haha?